# Create egg file without python distribution suffixed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I run python setup.py, it automatically appends the python distribution at the end and while distribution, makes users think, it only compatible with Python2 while the egg file is compatible with Python 3 as well.

Comment: Can you just run `setup.py` with python2 and python3 separately, and offer both?

Comment: No I can’t.. I want to use a single egg file for distribution